# How to create a custom style?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, styles, custom-controls

I have several View widgets in my axml file they looks like that:

```
 <View
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="2dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
     android:background="#c0c0c0" />
```

I don't want to repeat the code so I created styles.xml file in Values folder with the following content:

```
<resources>
  <style name="HorizontalLine">
       <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
       <item name="android:layout_height">2dp</item>
       <item name="android:layout_marginTop">1dp</item>
       <item name="marginBottom">5dp</item>
       <item name="android:background">#c0c0c0</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Now I'm trying to reference the style in my Views like that:

```
<View
     android:style="@style/HorizontalLine"
/>
```

But it doesn't work. I've tried all in internet to create style. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: try providing height and width to view in xml also

Comment: It's the same...

Comment: <View
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="20dp"
     android:style="@style/HorizontalLine"
/> try like this

Comment: can You check if BuildType is set to AndroidResource for this file (in properties)?

Comment: For the rest I'm OK. Right? I create the files where they have to be?

Comment: Rafal Malek how can I get there?

Comment: @proffstack right click on styles.xml, then properties

Comment: Yeah it's AndroidResource

Comment: try reference by *style* instead of *android:style*

Comment: It worked but style is underlined with blue line. I don't like that. Why is it?

Comment: I think it's some kind of Intellisense problem. But for sure style is a correct attribute

Comment: also in this item: *<item name="marginBottom">5dp</item>* you should change name to *android:layout_marginBottom*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is about how to use style in Xamarin.Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/material-theme/)

Replace your code with this:

`styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
  <style name="HorizontalLine">
       <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
       <item name="android:layout_height">2dp</item>
       <item name="android:layout_marginTop">1dp</item>
       <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
       <item name="android:background">#c0c0c0</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

`<item name="marginBottom">5dp</item>` it can not be recognized by the compiler.

`layout.xml`:

```
<View
     style="@style/HorizontalLine"
/>
```

Replace `android:style=` with `style=`, you can see it in the link.